# Can not read property ' _id ' of undefined error when using the express-validator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using 'express -validator ' to check my forms , in inserting this checking usually entretando the issue is occurring an error .
Can not read property ' _id ' of undefined .

code below:

Users controller

```
var validacao = require('../validacoes/usuarios');
edit:function(req, res){
        Usuario.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data){
            if(err){
                req.flash('erro', 'erro ao editar usuario' + err);
                res.redirect('/usuarios');
            }else{
                res.render('usuarios/edit', {dados: data})
            }
        });
    }, 

    update:function(req, res){
        if(validacao(req, res)){
            Usuario.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data){
                var model = data;
                model.nome = req.body.nome;
                model.site = req.body.site;
                model.email= req.body.email;
                model.save(function(err){
                    if(err){
                        req.flash('erro', 'erro ao editar usuario' + err);
                        res.render('usuarios/edit', {dados: model});
                    }else{
                        req.flash('info', 'registro atualizado com sucesso!');
                        res.redirect('/usuarios');
                    }   
                });
            });
        }else{
            res.render('usuarios/edit', {user: req.body});
        }
    }
```

the controller I export an external file where I have the validation rules are these:

code below:

```
 var url = require('url');

  module.exports = function(req, res){
  var createUrl = url.parse(req.url).pathname == "/usuarios/create";
  var updateUrl = !createUrl;   

  req.assert('nome', 'Informe o seu nome').notEmpty();
  req.assert('email', 'Email inválido').isEmail();
  req.assert('site', 'Site não tem a url válida').isURL();

     if(createUrl){
         req.assert('password', 'sua senha deve conter 6 ate 20  caracteres').len(6,20);
     }

 var validateErros = req.validationErrors() || [];

if(req.body.password != req.body.password_confirmar){
    validateErros.push({msg: 'Senhas diferentes'});
}

 if(validateErros.length > 0){
    validateErros.forEach(function(e){
        req.flash('erro', e.msg);
    });
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
}
```

thank you for attention

Comment: Ta meio estranho isso ae... o que o código de baixo tem a ver com o de cima ?

Comment: o de baixo são meu codigos de verificação as regras o de cima o controller

Comment: Can you show the complete error message ?

Comment: views\usuarios\edit.jade:11 9| br 10| hr > 11| form(method="POST", action="/usuarios/edit/#{dados._id}", role="form") 12| .form-group 13| label(for="Nome") Nome: 14| input(type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="1" value="#{dados.nome}" placeholder="Coloque o nome" ) Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Comment: Well, is the result of your query defined? You neither check the err nor assert that `data` is defined.

Comment: @ViniciusdeGouvea you should post an answer to your own question so that other users can learn as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Usuario.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data){
     if(err) {
           req.flash('erro', 'erro ao editar usuario' + err);
           res.redirect('/usuarios');
     } else {
           res.render('usuarios/edit', {dados: data})
     }
});
```

Well,  when req.params.id don't exists in the database, the err will  not exist, and value of data is null, make sure when case of data === null  and flash the message.

```
Usuario.findById(req.params.id, function(err, data){
    if(err) {
       req.flash('erro', 'erro ao editar usuario' + err);
       res.redirect('/usuarios');
     } else if (!data) {
       req.flash('erro', 'user don\'t exist');
       res.redirect('/usuarios');  
     }
     res.render('usuarios/edit', {dados: data})
});
```